# How to implement properly expire feature for collection in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, collections

I want to implement a collection where elements can expire and be deleted. Because I have little experience with Javascript I can't find the best approach. In another languages I would have used a thread for iterating over the collection cleaning up expired elements. But in Javascript this is not possible and I couldn't think of solutions except using `setInterval` function. So every time an element is inserted a callback function will be registered for cleaning up the element later.

```js
class Collection {
    constructor() {
        this.items = new Map()
    }

    put(key, value, expireIn) {
        this.items.set(key, value)
        setInterval(() => {
            this.items.delete(key)
        }, expireIn)
    }

    get(key) {
        return this.items.get(key)
    }
}
```

Do you think this approach can have some limit? For instance, is it fine call `setInterval` a lot of times? Are there any other way to implement it?

Comment: Use `setTimeout()`, not `setInterval()` for a one-shot timer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is fundamentally sound. Your use of Intervals has a problem, though.

It looks like you set a separate Interval for each item  in your collection, the purpose of which is to delete it when its time-to-live expires. But Intervals repeat until you cancel them. You should probably use a timeout here. And if somehow an item gets deleted from your collection be sure to cancel its timeout.

A more efficient way to handle this sort of thing:

- don't use  separate timeout for each object in your collection.
- make your get() method check whether your item has expired, and return null if so.
- set up an interval for each collection to run every so often (a few seconds or minutes) and delete all expired items.

I use a module called node-cache for this purpose. https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cache  It works flawlessly for me for months of uptime and counting.